# XML format data to display in sql Table only with specific columns (no duplicates)

Tags: sql-server, xml

### The following XML variable should show a table having columns like:-

### Identifier  |  ModelVariant  |  BomElement

```
declare @xmlData XML='<UICK>
<KEM count="2" change="created">
<Identifier>ZAP46817</Identifier>
<ChangeLevel>1</ChangeLevel>
<Editor>GGV</Editor>
<ReleaseDateTime>2017-06-12T05:40:40</ReleaseDateTime>
<EngineeringScope>2528R ''P''  RELEASE</EngineeringScope>
<Reason>NYLON HOSE E "P" RELEASE FOR NEW ZEALANDMATURITY CHANGE</Reason>
<Status>REFER PROJECT</Status>
<LegalRelevance>no</LegalRelevance>
<SpecialToolsRequirement>N</SpecialToolsRequirement>
<CircularTechnicalLetterAvailability>N</CircularTechnicalLetterAvailability>
<ExaustRelevance>N</ExaustRelevance>
<StopNoticeType>N</StopNoticeType>
<Request>
  <Organization>requester</Organization>
  <Person>VINOTHKUMA</Person>
  <Department>TP/ACI</Department>
  <DateTime>2017-06-02T00:00:00</DateTime>
</Request>
<Update>
  <Organization>main editor</Organization>
  <Person>VINOTHKUMA</Person>
  <Department>TP/ACI</Department>
  <DateTime>2017-06-02T00:00:00</DateTime>
</Update>
<Approval>
  <Organization>approver</Organization>
  <Person>RPRABHU</Person>
  <Department>TP/ACI</Department>
  <DateTime>2017-06-09T00:00:00</DateTime>
</Approval>
<Authorization>
  <Organization>authorizer</Organization>
  <Person>VJAJI</Person>
  <Department>TP/ACI</Department>
  <DateTime>2017-06-09T00:00:00</DateTime>
</Authorization>
<ProductDocumentationUpdate>
  <Organization>product documentation editor</Organization>
  <Person>VIGNEB</Person>
  <Department>TP/AIH</Department>
  <DateTime>2017-06-06T00:00:00</DateTime>
</ProductDocumentationUpdate>
<Further-1>
  <Organization>CONTROLLED BY       </Organization>
  <Person>SARAVANAN</Person>
  <Department>TP/AIH</Department>
</Further-1>
<ProjectIdentifier>DICVPVH-Y17</ProjectIdentifier>
<ProjectName>HDT PROJECT 2017  HDT VEHICLE SERIES 2017</ProjectName>
<ChangeRequestIdentifier>NO CR</ChangeRequestIdentifier>
<TechnicalData>no</TechnicalData>
<Distributor>FQ</Distributor>
<KemType>A</KemType>
<StopNoticeCauseCode>U</StopNoticeCauseCode>
<ChangeCategories>
  <Category>
    <Identifier>5</Identifier>
    <Name>MaturityLevelChange</Name>
  </Category>
</ChangeCategories>
<MATERIALMASTERS>
  <PART_MATERIALMASTER count="1" change="modified">
    <Identifier>A4004204731</Identifier>
    <ChangeLevel>3</ChangeLevel>
    <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
    <EnglishName>ZB COMPRESSED AIR LINE/MB/2528R 6X25700 ABS/TEST CON</EnglishName>
    <SpanishName>ZB TUB.P.AIRE COMP / MB/2528R 6X2 5700WB ABS/TEST CON</SpanishName>
    <PortugueseName>ZB TBO.AR COMPRIM. / MB/2528R 6X2 5700WB ABS/TEST CON</PortugueseName>
    <FrenchName>ZB COND AIR COMPR / MB/2528R 6X2 5700WB ABS/TEST CON</FrenchName>
    <DrawingGeometryChangeLevel>1</DrawingGeometryChangeLevel>
    <SecurityRelevance>N</SecurityRelevance>
    <CertificationRelevance>N</CertificationRelevance>
    <PartsListElementType>assembly</PartsListElementType>
    <ReferenceDrawingType>06.04.2017</ReferenceDrawingType>
    <CADIdType>G</CADIdType>
    <FlashwareDocumentationRelevantPart>no</FlashwareDocumentationRelevantPart>
    <TheftRelevantPart>no</TheftRelevantPart>
    <ReleaseItemType>SERIE</ReleaseItemType>
    <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP46817</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    <LeadingDocumentationGroup>KH</LeadingDocumentationGroup>
    <SharedPartFlag>no</SharedPartFlag>
    <ChangeText>MATURITY CHANGE</ChangeText>
    <TermID>0500002680</TermID>
    <RSK>
      <RSK-NL>LUCHTDRUKLEIDING</RSK-NL>
      <RSK-PL>PRZEWOD SPREZ. POW.</RSK-PL>
      <RSK-DA>TRYKLUFTROER</RSK-DA>
      <RSK-FR>CONDUITE DAIR COMPRIME</RSK-FR>
      <RSK-HU>SURITETTLEVEGOVEZETEK</RSK-HU>
      <RSK-TR>BASINCLI HAVA HATTI</RSK-TR>
      <RSK-CS>POTRUBI TLAKOVZDUSNE</RSK-CS>
      <RSK-DE>DRUCKLUFTLTG.</RSK-DE>
      <RSK-SV>TRYCKLUFTSLEDNING</RSK-SV>
      <RSK-SK>VEDENIE VZDUCHU</RSK-SK>
      <RSK-EN>COMPRESSED AIR LINE</RSK-EN>
      <RSK-ES>TUBERIA</RSK-ES>
      <RSK-IT>TUBAZIONE PNEUMATICA</RSK-IT>
      <RSK-PT>TUBO DO AR COMPRIMIDO</RSK-PT>
      <RSK-BG>??????????? ?????.????.</RSK-BG>
      <RSK-RU>????????????</RSK-RU>
      <RSK-ZH>??????</RSK-ZH>
    </RSK>
  </PART_MATERIALMASTER>
  <PART_MATERIALMASTER count="2" change="modified">
    <Identifier>A4004209329</Identifier>
    <ChangeLevel>3</ChangeLevel>
    <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
    <EnglishName>ZB COMPRESSED AIR LINE/ACC 6X2 5700W/G131/BS4/PTO/RHD</EnglishName>
    <SpanishName>ZB TUB.P.AIRE COMP / ACC 6X2 5700WB/BS4/PTO/RHD</SpanishName>
    <PortugueseName>ZB TUBO DO AR COMPRIMIDO / ACC 6X2 5700WB/BS4/PTO/RHD</PortugueseName>
    <FrenchName>ZB CONDUITE AIR COMPRIME / ACC 6X2 5700WB/BS4/PTO/RHD</FrenchName>
    <DrawingGeometryChangeLevel>1</DrawingGeometryChangeLevel>
    <SecurityRelevance>N</SecurityRelevance>
    <CertificationRelevance>N</CertificationRelevance>
    <PartsListElementType>assembly</PartsListElementType>
    <ReferenceDrawingType>07.04.2017</ReferenceDrawingType>
    <CADIdType>G</CADIdType>
    <FlashwareDocumentationRelevantPart>no</FlashwareDocumentationRelevantPart>
    <TheftRelevantPart>no</TheftRelevantPart>
    <ReleaseItemType>SERIE</ReleaseItemType>
    <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP46817</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    <LeadingDocumentationGroup>KH</LeadingDocumentationGroup>
    <SharedPartFlag>no</SharedPartFlag>
    <ChangeText>MATURITY CHANGE</ChangeText>
    <TermID>0500002680</TermID>
    <RSK>
      <RSK-NL>LUCHTDRUKLEIDING</RSK-NL>
      <RSK-PL>PRZEWOD SPREZ. POW.</RSK-PL>
      <RSK-DA>TRYKLUFTROER</RSK-DA>
      <RSK-FR>CONDUITE DAIR COMPRIME</RSK-FR>
      <RSK-HU>SURITETTLEVEGOVEZETEK</RSK-HU>
      <RSK-TR>BASINCLI HAVA HATTI</RSK-TR>
      <RSK-CS>POTRUBI TLAKOVZDUSNE</RSK-CS>
      <RSK-DE>DRUCKLUFTLTG.</RSK-DE>
      <RSK-SV>TRYCKLUFTSLEDNING</RSK-SV>
      <RSK-SK>VEDENIE VZDUCHU</RSK-SK>
      <RSK-EN>COMPRESSED AIR LINE</RSK-EN>
      <RSK-ES>TUBERIA</RSK-ES>
      <RSK-IT>TUBAZIONE PNEUMATICA</RSK-IT>
      <RSK-PT>TUBO DO AR COMPRIMIDO</RSK-PT>
      <RSK-BG>??????????? ?????.????.</RSK-BG>
      <RSK-RU>????????????</RSK-RU>
      <RSK-ZH>??????</RSK-ZH>
    </RSK>
  </PART_MATERIALMASTER>
</MATERIALMASTERS>
<BOMMASTERS>
  <LOWER_BOM_HEADER count="1" change="modified">
    <ParentBomElement>A4004204731</ParentBomElement>
    <BomPosition change="deleted">
      <BomElement>A4004291808</BomElement>
      <Position>000010</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>V</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, D, FH, FR, U, UD, Z</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP718915</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="created">
      <BomElement>A4004291808</BomElement>
      <Position>000010</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>P</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, FH</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP46817</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
  </LOWER_BOM_HEADER>
  <LOWER_BOM_HEADER count="2" change="modified">
    <ParentBomElement>Z40086626</ParentBomElement>
    <BomPosition change="deleted">
      <BomElement>A4004209329</BomElement>
      <Position>000100</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>V</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, FR, U, UM, DW, J, SR, TD, TY, Z, EK, ZV</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP31815</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="created">
      <BomElement>A4004209329</BomElement>
      <Position>000100</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>P</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, FH</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP46817</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
  </LOWER_BOM_HEADER>
  <LOWER_BOM_HEADER count="3" change="modified">
    <ParentBomElement>A4004209329</ParentBomElement>
    <BomPosition change="deleted">
      <BomElement>A4004296901</BomElement>
      <Position>000100</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>V</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, FR, U, UM, DW, J, SR, TD, TY, Z, EK, ZV</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP31815</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="created">
      <BomElement>A4004296901</BomElement>
      <Position>000100</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>P</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, FH</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP46817</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
  </LOWER_BOM_HEADER>
  <LOWER_BOM_HEADER count="4" change="modified">
    <ParentBomElement>Z40086699</ParentBomElement>
    <BomPosition change="deleted">
      <BomElement>A4004204731</BomElement>
      <Position>000100</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>V</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, D, FH, FR, U, UD, Z</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP718915</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="created">
      <BomElement>A4004204731</BomElement>
      <Position>000100</Position>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <UnitOfQuantity>each</UnitOfQuantity>
      <MaturityLevel>P</MaturityLevel>
      <Plant>FQ, FH</Plant>
      <ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>ZAP46817</ReleaseDesignChangeOrder>
    </BomPosition>
  </LOWER_BOM_HEADER>
  <UPPER_BOM_HEADER count="5" change="modified">
    <ModelVariant>F400216220D130390</ModelVariant>
    <BomPosition change="deleted">
      <Group>S429</Group>
      <Scope>SN42240</Scope>
      <Position>000280</Position>
      <BomElement>Z40086626</BomElement>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <MaturityLevel>T</MaturityLevel>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="deleted">
      <Group>S429</Group>
      <Scope>SN42240</Scope>
      <Position>000300</Position>
      <BomElement>Z40086699</BomElement>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <MaturityLevel>T</MaturityLevel>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="created">
      <Group>S429</Group>
      <Scope>SN42240</Scope>
      <Position>000280</Position>
      <BomElement>Z40086626</BomElement>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <MaturityLevel>P</MaturityLevel>
    </BomPosition>
    <BomPosition change="created">
      <Group>S429</Group>
      <Scope>SN42240</Scope>
      <Position>000300</Position>
      <BomElement>Z40086699</BomElement>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <MaturityLevel>P</MaturityLevel>
    </BomPosition>
  </UPPER_BOM_HEADER>
</BOMMASTERS>
</KEM>
</UICK>'
```

---

I'm using the below code to fetch data, but it is not showing properly.
It should show -> inside  tag one Identifier value, then multiple ModelVariant value inside UPPER_BOM_HEADER and BomElement value inside BomPosition node. Exactly, is should be as per the below URLs.
The parent node  contains one  now, it may contain more number of  node same like above details.

---

```
SELECT  doc.col.value('(/ UICK / KEM/Identifier/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') Identifier,doc.col.value('(/ UICK / KEM/BOMMASTERS / UPPER_BOM_HEADER/ModelVariant/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ModelVariant,doc.col.value('(/ UICK / KEM/BOMMASTERS / UPPER_BOM_HEADER / BomPosition/BomElement/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') BomElement FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ UICK / KEM/*') doc(col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear... Next time please try to **reduce!!!** your sample data to a needed minimum to see what you need and please provide the **expected output**.

My magic crystall ball tells me, that you might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT  @xmlData.value('(/UICK/KEM/Identifier/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') Identifier
       ,u_bom.value('(ModelVariant/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ModelVariant
       ,bomP.value('(BomElement/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') BomElement 
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/UICK/KEM/BOMMASTERS/UPPER_BOM_HEADER') A(u_bom)
CROSS APPLY u_bom.nodes('BomPosition') AS B(bomP)
```

### UPDATE: For multiple `<KEM>`

(**hint** Please avoid chameleon questions!)

Try it like this:

```
SELECT  kem.value('(Identifier/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') Identifier
       ,u_bom.value('(ModelVariant/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ModelVariant
       ,bomP.value('(BomElement/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') BomElement 
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/UICK/KEM') AS A(kem)
CROSS APPLY kem.nodes('BOMMASTERS/UPPER_BOM_HEADER') B(u_bom)
CROSS APPLY u_bom.nodes('BomPosition') AS C(bomP)
```

Comment: Hi Shnugo, Thanks for answering this question. Its retrieving 'ModelVariant' and 'BomElement' column. Only 'Identifier' value showing one value, when multiple <KEM><Identifier> exists, may be my question was not that much clear. I gave one part of the code in this question and here only one <KEM><Identifier> exists.Just imagine if same kind of 5 <KEM> blocks would be there in root <UICK>. And <Identifier> value would be different for each <KEM> then, specific <Identifier> value for respective <ModelVariant> and <BomElement>. If you need, I can post  another block code for proper understanding.

Comment: Thanks Shnugo for your updates. Checked this, it seems good. I need to check in details and update you.